# splitting a number(int) within a column in DF into 4 new columns R

Tags: r

Below is the output of one of my columns within a DF I've created from importing a weekly summary.csv.
these are unique codes and each code should only be 4 number long ie 8400, 9070 etc.
when the summary document is produced all the codes are bunched together without commas or indentation.
like below:

```
1 84709070
2 75508470
3 8400
3 750084009100
```

is there a way I can turn the above into 4 new rows that split the numbers start from the first int by 4 places ie output the fourth row would look like:

```
tariff1, tariff2, tariff3, tariff4
7500     8400     9100     none
```

I managed to create an abomination in excel but it hardly works at the best of time and id prefer to use R for everything, we are getting about 30k of these entries a week would really streamline processes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tidyr::separate` mentioning the positions where you want to split in `sep`.

```
tidyr::separate(df, V2, paste0('col', 1:4), sep = seq(4, 12, 4), convert = TRUE)

#  V1 col1 col2 col3 col4
#1  1 8470 9070   NA   NA
#2  2 7550 8470   NA   NA
#3  3 8400   NA   NA   NA
#4  3 7500 8400 9100   NA
```

`seq` generates the sequence of positions.

```
seq(4, 12, 4)
#[1]  4  8 12
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L), V2 = c(84709070, 75508470, 
8400, 750084009100)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R option, which defines a function `f` to split the numbers

```
f <- function(x) t(`length<-`(as.numeric(sapply(seq(1,nchar(x),by = 4), function(k) substr(x,k,k+3))),4))
dfout <- cbind(df,data.frame(Vectorize(f)(df$V2)))
```

such that

```
  V1           V2   X1   X2   X3   X4
1  1     84709070 8470 7550 8400 7500
2  2     75508470 9070 8470   NA 8400
3  3         8400   NA   NA   NA 9100
4  3 750084009100   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(V1 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L), V2 = c(84709070, 75508470, 
8400, 750084009100)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `strsplit` from `base R`

```
lst1 <- strsplit(as.character(df$V2), "(?<=....)", perl = TRUE)
df[paste0('col', 1:4)] <- do.call(rbind, lapply(lst1, 
              `length<-`, max(lengths(lst1))+1))
df <- type.convert(df, as.is = TRUE)
```

-output

```
df
#  V1           V2 col1 col2 col3 col4
#1  1     84709070 8470 9070   NA   NA
#2  2     75508470 7550 8470   NA   NA
#  3         8400 8400   NA   NA   NA
#4  3 750084009100 7500 8400 9100   NA
```

---

Or using `read.fwf` from `base R`

```
df[paste0('col', 1:4)] <-  read.fwf(file = textConnection(as.character(df$V2)),
              widths = c(4, 4, 4, 4))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L), V2 = c(84709070, 75508470, 
8400, 750084009100)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-4L))
```